# Laravel 5.5 display list of product order by count on relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I want to display the list of product that order by the most frequently sold items, so i made the relation to shipping_detail table but I got an error. here's the code :

```
Produk::select('product.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(shipping_detail.product_code) as total'))
      ->leftJoin('shipping_detail', 'shipping_detail.product_code', '=', 'product.product_code')
      ->whereIn('product.category_id', $cat)
      ->orWhere('product.category_id', $prod_cat_id)
      ->groupBy('product.product_code')
      ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
      ->limit(7)
      ->get();
```

The error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'store.product.category_id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

do I have to put all the column of product table in group by or there is another way to do this more simple ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel

Comment: solved .. thanks @AndriyLozynskiy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your mysql have strict enforced in the `config/database.php` file

If it is change to false. ie

```
'strict' => false,
```