# Laravel - select rows with first occurance of column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have DB table `urls` similar to this

```
id | user_id | name
----------------------------
1  | 56      | John
2  | 25      | Carry
3  | 56      | Jim
4  | 12      | Jolana
5  | 12      | Ava
```

What I need to do is to select the rows with **the first occurance** of `user_id` ordered in DESC by `id`. In this case it would mean to select rows with IDs `5`, `3` and `2`.

Can this be achieved somehow using Eloquent, or if not, pure SQL? I can imagine writing a script for this but I would like to make it work with one query.

Comment: what you have tried? do you have a model or you want to go into [raw sql](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database) (that i personally wont endorse like the two answer below). if you had a model named `Url`, roughly, you can call the following `Url:all()->orderByDesc('id')->groupBy('user_id')`. do note however about this [config perks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41571271/4648586).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id);
```

Comment: I don't really understand the query, could you please adjust it to fit my example with table name `urls`?

Comment: @JakubSzymsza Here you go [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b417eefaa39679ab9020d2684577784). I guess you need  MAX not MIN.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab_name) sub
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo - MariaDB 10.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=92757e77fd901f2d9475edeb5f356bc5)**

**[DBFiddle Demo - MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92757e77fd901f2d9475edeb5f356bc5)**

Comment: I keep getting syntax error near `PARTITION BY` in both MySQL and MariaDB on my server

Comment: @JakubSzymsza Probably you are using outdated version.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 10.0.34 yet it still doesn't work for some reason. But nevermind, Gordon's solution works. Thank you.

Comment: @JakubSzymsza `ROW_NUMBER` was intorduced in `MariaDB 10.2.0` > `10.0.34`