# A.* isn't in GROUP BY with left join on laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, left-join, laravel-query-builder

```
   $search_alls=
    DB::table('a16s as A')
    ->select('A.id')
    // ->select('A.*')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yshow'))
    ->leftjoin('a16s_likes as B', function($join) {
        $join->on('A.id', '=', 'B.p_id');
        })
    ->groupBy('A.id')
    ->get();
```

when I use above select('A.id') is work well.

But when I use  select('A.*') to select all A cloumn 
I got the error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'employee.A.name' isn't in GROUP BY
```

PS:employee is my DB name
The column on A table is

```
id name ....
1  john
2  mary
3  susan
```

How can I select all column by the leftjoin?
the column A.id is one to many relationship to the B.p_id column.

Comment: Is `id` a primary key column?  If not, then selecting `A.*` is not valid.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by

Comment: disabling only_full_group_by in mysql may solve the error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen id is a primary key column

Comment: @afsalc thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by not working - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this issue you need to specify required columns in select list and group by clause

```
$search_alls=DB::table('a16s as A')
                ->select('A.id','A.name')
                ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yshow'))
                ->leftjoin('a16s_likes as B', function($join) {
                    $join->on('A.id', '=', 'B.p_id');
                })
                ->groupBy('A.id')
                ->groupBy('A.name');
    ->get();
```

> As per newer release mysql 5.7 does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause

[**12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

---

As per docs

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) is not enabled by default

Comment: It's true. I cannot use * and must to grouBy(...) all column. It works~thanks a lot! But not any solution to use * as it is convenient?

Comment: @robspin To use `*` you need to perform aggregation of a16s_likes in seperate sub clause and then join this clause with your table

Answer (score 2):

use select('A.*') to select all columns

```
 $search_alls=
    DB::table('a16s as A') 
    ->select('A.*')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN B.approve = 1 ELSE 0 END) as Yshow'))
    ->leftjoin('a16s_likes as B', function($join) {
        $join->on('A.id', '=', 'B.p_id');
        })
    ->groupBy('A.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: How does this fix the OP?

Comment: solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

I saw your issue in detail.
and I've faced same issue.
in database.php, there are below setting

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

When I set strict property as false, it was working, and i've solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off sctrict mode in Laravel application.

go to `config/database.php`

under the MySQL set

```
strict => false
```

and it will start working.

Hope this helps.