# sql isn't in GROUP BY using query builder laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image]
I want to take how much amount of data based on the product_id taken from the table vote. on laravel this query does not work well but when i try it in mysql i run it fine is there any other solution?

this is a successfully executed query through mysql :

```
select count(product_id) as total, `v`.*, `p`.`name` from `votes` as `v` left join `products` as `p` on `p`.`id` = (select p1.id from products as p1 where v.product_id = p1.id ) group by v.product_id
```

result :
[image]

and it's a query on laravel that I use using query builder :

```
$count = DB::table('votes as v')->leftJoin('products as p',function($join){
  $join->on('p.id','=',DB::raw('(select p1.id from products as p1 where v.product_id = p1.id )'));
})->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'),'v.*','p.name')->groupBy('v.product_id')->get();
dd($count);
```

and i got this error :

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'lookbubbledrink.v.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(*) as
>   total, `v`.*, `p`.`name` from `votes` as `v` left join `products` as
>   `p` on `p`.`id` = (select p1.id from products as p1 where v.product_id
>   = p1.id ) group by `v`.`product_id`

I have to use group by product_id only to calculate how much amount of data based on the number of product_id in the vote.

Comment: Configurations in newer versions of MySQL disable the partial group by uniquely permitted by MySQL. In such configurations, all non-aggregated fields selected must be included in the group by clause. Since you're selecting `v.*` you will need to include every field from `v` in the group by.

Comment: "on laravel this query does not work well but when i try it in mysql i run it fine" On MySQL it also does NOT run fine your query will generate wrong results..Laraval most likely set the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode active for the php mysql client

Comment: is there any other way to generate such data? @Uueerdo

Comment: Use a delivered table (subquery) to count and group by product_id and inner join that result set back with the other data only possible way.

Comment: Including `v.*` in such a query doesn't even really make much sense; `*` from which v row of the numerous ones that could have the same product_id?

Comment: can you explain how? @RaymondNijland

Comment: Yes but you need to add in a example data place it on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com and add in the expected output as ascii data table (text formatted)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by not working - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using strict mode in laravel. By the you can tweak it to your needs.

got to `config/database.php`  in set `strict=>false` and you are good to go.

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```