# How to use `GroupBy` and `join` together in Laravel SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have two tables `clinic` and `service`. In `service` table there is a column `clinic_id`. Now I want to retrieve all the services under every column.

I am giving some demo data for better understand.

clinic table data

```
{id:1,name:clinic1},{id:2,name: clinic2}
```

service table data

```
{id: 1, clinic_id: 1, name: service11}, 
{id: 2, clinic_id: 1, name: service12}, 
{id: 3, clinic_id: 2, name: service21}, 
{id: 4, clinic_id: 2, name: service22}
```

Now I want to retrieve data like below

```
{clinic_name: clinic1}:[{service_name: service11}, {service_name: service12}],
{clinic_name: clinic2}:[{service_name: service21}, {service_name: service22}]
```

What is the SQL query for Laravel ?

Comment: What are you trying to do, and can you include some sample data which explains that?  The error is a common one, stemming from using `SELECT *` (i.e. all columns) along with a `GROUP BY` clause on only one column.  You can't do that in certain modes of MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by not working - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen...I have to table 'clinic` and `service`...in service I have `clinic_id`...now I want to get all the services under every clinic

Comment: @Bugfixer...not at all...I have already change `strict => false` in `config/database.php`

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned into question Eloquent relationships can be used to accomplish above task

According to documentation of Laravel

> A "one-to-many" relationship is used to define relationships where a
>   single model owns any amount of other models. For example, a blog post
>   may have an infinite number of comments. Like all other Eloquent
>   relationships, one-to-many relationships are defined by placing a
>   function on your Eloquent model

Please try following code snippet

> app\Models\Clinic.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clinic extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Service','clinic_id','id');
    }
}
?>
```

> app\Http\Controllers\ClinicController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Clinic;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;

class ClinicController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{

}

 function index()
 {
   $Clinics = Clinic::with('services')->get();
 }
}
?>
```