# Query distinct row in Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to get distinct row from this. I use:

```
DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->distinct()->get();
```

But it still give result with 3 rows. I expected 2 rows.

How I can fix this?

Comment: Every row is distinct and so the `->distinct()` gives you a correct result. You want distinct with respect to which column?

Comment: I want to distinct with product_id column. But when I put product_id to distinct function, it still give me 3 column

Comment: ok, do you use `Eloquent` models? If yes, what's the model name for `dmspro_mys_campaign_product`? Also, how would like other column values to be if you want distinct product_id?

Comment: I create a new post for clearly description. Hope you help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216579/left-join-with-a-distinct-query-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the field name inside the distinct function. like this(in case if you want distinct based on 'compeign_code' column)

```
DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->distinct('compeign_code')->get();
```

in case if you want to distinct the field based on more than one column value then you can use the select method.

Comment: my campaign_code is different each row. I tried put product_id into distinct function but it still give me 3 rows

Comment: As you can see that the id field is different in each row. So in such cases, you will need to use the select method. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the answer is correct. District rows give you the results where every row is unique. Since there are slight variations between all three rows, you get all three because no row is exactly equal to another row.

I hope I could help,
Sebastian

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You need a distinct value from `dmspro_mys_campaign_product` table so Database query needs pass column name.

```
DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->distinct('product_id')->get();
```

Comment: I tried put product_id into distinct function but it still give me 3 rows

Comment: @Tomato You need to use `select('product_id')`  method in your DB query.

Comment: but it will give my only 1 column. Anyway to get all column with distinct product_id

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to mention the column name in `distinct('compeign_code')`.

```
 DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->distinct('compeign_code')->get();
```

Or you can try

```
 DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->groupby('product_id')->distinct()->get();
```

If you want to get only one column then you may use this.

```
DB::table('dmspro_mys_campaign_product')->distinct()->select('product_id');
```

Comment: my campaign_code is different each row. I tried put product_id into distinct function but it still give me 3 rows

Comment: if I add select, it will give me only one column. Anyway to get a row with distinct column

Comment: I mentioned if you use select then you'll get only only one column

Comment: sorry! I try your second query with group by. I got error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'test.dmspro_mys_campaign_product.campaign_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select distinct * from `dmspro_mys_campaign_product` group by `product_id`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel see this for group by