# Left join with a distinct query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables like this:

product_master:

[image]

campaign_product:

[image]

I use this query to get data from product_master and campaign_product tables:

```
$oSelect = $this->select(
    "{$this->table}.product_code",
    "{$this->table}.product_display_name",
    'dmspro_mys_campaign_product.campaign_code',
    'dmspro_mys_campaign_product.product_id',
)->leftJoin(
    'dmspro_mys_campaign_product', 
    \DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM dmspro_mys_campaign_product"), '=', "{$this->table}.product_id"
);

return $oSelect->get();
```

But as you can see, in my campaign_product table, there are 2 rows same product_id, so my result is duplicated row:

[image]

Now I want it return only 1 product_id by distinct query.
I tried this:

```
 ->leftJoin(\DB::raw("(SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM dmspro_mys_campaign_product) as cp"), 'cp.product_id', '=', "{$this->table}.product_id");
```

But it's error about my query syntax.

How I can do this?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help into providing reproducible data example..

Comment: *"Now I want it return only 1 product_id by distinct query. I tried this:"*  Which one of the two? As from the looks of it this dataset example is missing a logical order to get a deterministic sort going..

Comment: The first one. I want it return only the first one after distinct query.

Comment: *"The first one."* "first" one is not possible with this dataset as SQL is unsorted nothing in your dataset will say thats the "first" matching record ..

Comment: So how can I do?

Comment: .. unless offcource campaign_id can be used for thats not clear from the question/data as it seams to be a "group" separator ... Anyhow see mine first comment ... Then we can start giving answers as nobody most likely will covert those image into SQL statements by hand to test with ...

Comment: as @RaymondNijland said, to not have dupplicate result by `product_code`, you will need to do a group by or a sub query. In a group by, you can only select aggregated fields which will need you to set a logic for the field `campaign_code`. In a sub query, you will have more free selection but if you dont want volatile result, you will need to set a logic here too AND the query will be very slow.

Comment: Ok I think I will use sub query. But can you give me an example code. I still not know what I should write

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MySQL, Run the below query before run your main query.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```