# Laravel Eloquent Multiple Where with count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Following is the SQL query that I need to perform on laravel eloquent. SQL returns expected output.

```
SELECT
  orders.id,
  orders.`status`,
  order_type,
  COUNT(order_type) as count
FROM
  orders
WHERE
  orders.`status` = 0 && order_type = 1
ORDER BY
  orders.id DESC
```

what I have tried on laravel is below

```
        $receved = Order::select('status', 'order_type')->where('status',0);
        $relase = $receved->where('order_type',  1)->get();
        $bulk = $receved->where('order_type', 2)->get();
        $distiribute = $receved->where('order_type', 3)->get();

        return response()->json([

            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Statement Updated',
            'orderStatment' =>  [
                'relaseCount' => count($relase),
                'bulkCount' =>  count($bulk),
                'distiributeCount' => count($distiribute)
            ],
        ], 200);
```

I seeking recommendation/suggestion to operate this in a correct way

The output I getting on laravel is

```
            'orderStatment' =>  [
                'relaseCount' => 14,
                'bulkCount' =>  0,
                'distiributeCount' => 0
            ],
```

the output of expectation and SQL produce is

```
                    'orderStatment' =>  [
                        'relaseCount' => 14,
                        'bulkCount' =>  5,
                        'distiributeCount' => 4
                    ],
```

There are 8 Different type of `status` and 3 different types of `order_type` available on Table I want to get each `order_type` count of every status

Comment: What are you getting vs what are you expecting?

Comment: @BrianThompson i updated the question and with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck doing it all in one query, then getting the data back out.

```
$receved = Order::select('status', 'order_type', DB::raw('COUNT(id) as order_count'))->where('status',0)
              ->groupBy('order_type')
              ->get();
```

This will give you a collection of all of the order types and their counts in one query. After that, you can get the data back out.

```
$bulk = $relase = $distiribute = 0;
foreach($receved as $rec) {
      if($rec->order_type == 1) $relase = $rec->order_count;
      elseif($rec->order_type == 2) $bulk = $rec->order_count;
      elseif($rec->order_type == 3) $distiribute = $rec->order_count;
}
```

Comment: which returns an error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055`

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? I might have mistyped something, but I can't see it

Comment: `message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'vgc.orders.status' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `status`, `order_type`, COUNT(id) as order_count from `orders` where `status` = 0 group by `order_type`)"

Comment: Ah ha, that darn GROUP BY message. Add `DB::statement("set @@sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'");` before your query. Or in `config/database.php`, change `strict => false` under `mysql`

Comment: changing `config/database.php, change strict => false`. works. can you explain what it does

Comment: Information at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800411/mysql-isnt-in-group-by

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is due to the fact that all of the following statements are manipulating the same query builder object:

```php
$receved = Order::select('status', 'order_type')->where('status',0);
$relase = $receved->where('order_type',  1)->get();
$bulk = $receved->where('order_type', 2)->get();
$distiribute = $receved->where('order_type', 3)->get();
```

So the actual queries created will be something like this:

**All start with:** `select status, order_type from orders where status = 0 and`

1. `order_type = 1;`
2. `order_type = 1 and order_type = 2`;
3. `order_type = 1 and order_type = 2 and order_type = 3`;

This is why the last two queries return 0. It's expected once you see the resulting query.

You can verify this by logging the query (see [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141045/9381601), or the [docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#debugging)).

`$receved` is actually getting the `where` clauses attached to it each time. So you're not just starting with the original statement, but **building** onto it each time you call `where`.