# Convert GROUP_CONCAT in SQL Query into Laravel Query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

this is my SQL query:

```
SELECT pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran,
       pendaftaran.nama,
       pendaftaran.nim,
       pilihan_daftar.id_pilihan,
       pilihan_daftar.alasan_pil,
       Group_concat(dinas_biro.nama_dinasbiro) AS nama_dinas
FROM   pendaftaran
       JOIN pilihan_daftar
         ON pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran = pilihan_daftar.id_pendaftaran
       JOIN dinas_biro
         ON dinas_biro.id_dinasbiro = pilihan_daftar.id_pilihan
GROUP  BY pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran;
```

then, i convert into laravel query:

```
Pendaftaran::join('pilihan_daftar','pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran','=','pilihan_daftar.id_pendaftaran') 
->join('dinas_biro','dinas_biro.id_dinasbiro','=','pilihan_daftar.id_pilihan')
->select(
    'pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran',
    'pendaftaran.nama',
    'pendaftaran.nim',
    'pilihan_daftar.id_pilihan',
    'pilihan_daftar.alasan_pil',
    DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(dinas_biro.nama_dinasbiro) as nama_dinas')
)
->groupBy('pendaftaran.id_pendaftaran')
->get();
```

But error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'keanggotaan_bem.pendaftaran.nama' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select
> `pendaftaran`.`id_pendaftaran`, `pendaftaran`.`nama`,
> `pendaftaran`.`nim`, `pilihan_daftar`.`id_pilihan`,
> `pilihan_daftar`.`alasan_pil`, GROUP_CONCAT(dinas_biro.nama_dinasbiro)
> as nama_dinas from `pendaftaran` inner join `pilihan_daftar` on
> `pendaftaran`.`id_pendaftaran` = `pilihan_daftar`.`id_pendaftaran`
> inner join `dinas_biro` on `dinas_biro`.`id_dinasbiro` =
> `pilihan_daftar`.`id_pilihan` group by `pendaftaran`.`id_pendaftaran`)

Can someone help me :(

Comment: Has it the same error when you run your query on a MySQL client?

Comment: Check if mysql strict mode is enabled in config/databases.php. If it is, disable it. If that doesn't fix your query, try adding more fields from your select to the group by.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by not working - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571271/group-by-not-working-laravel)

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `pendaftaran`?